# Expressing $y=\lfloor rx\rfloor$ in PA

Tags: real-numbers, peano-axioms

The formula:
$$y=\lfloor x\sqrt2\rfloor$$
is expressible in first-order PA, as:
$$y^2<2x^2<(y+1)^2$$
So, even though $\sqrt2$ isn't a natural number, we can still represent a formula with $\sqrt2$ in it.

My question is: For what real numbers $r$ can the sentence:
$$y=\lfloor rx\rfloor$$
be expressed in first-order PA? (Does $\pi$ work? $e$? What about noncomputable numbers?)

Comment: (I'm thinking that we can use series approximations for $\pi$ and $e$.)

Comment: For $e$ and $\pi$ the relation is recursive, and hence representable.